# ¿Cómo puedo detectar el país mediante la ip?

Tags: php

Me preguntaba cómo captar el país de un usuario mediante su ip automáticamente al momento de poner su datos en el login y ingresar. Algo así:
***Pones sus datos y ingresa correctamente --> Capta el país mediante su ip --> Hace un UPDATE en la base de datos colocando el país que capto (VE, ES, AR e etc..) UPDATE users SET pais = 'acá el país que capto' WHERE username = '" . USERNAME . "' (USERNAME es la variable para el usuario mediante SESSION).***

Alguna recomendacion de como hacerlo.

*Seleccionar IP del usuario*
**SELECT ip_register FROM users WHERE '". USERNAME ."'**

Comment: No hay una forma directa de hacer lo que pides desde PHP solamente. Necesitas conectarte a alguna API en internet que provea la información; o si el server no se conecta a internet tener una base de datos local con IPs de proveedores del mundo que debes actualizar cada cierto tiempo. Observa esta respuesta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650006/get-country-of-ip-address-with-php (en inglés) donde se discuten muchas opciones.

Answer (score 1):

En javascript:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script language="JavaScript" src="http://www.geoplugin.net/javascript.gp" type="text/javascript"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <script language="Javascript"> 
    document.write("Bienvenidos a nuestro visitante Jeff de : "+geoplugin_city()+", "+geoplugin_countryName()); 
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

En php utilizando la api http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp

```
  <?php
$geoPlugin_array = unserialize( file_get_contents('http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip=' . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) );

if ( $geoPlugin_array['geoplugin_currencyCode'] == 'UU' ) { //let's use a different base currency

    $geoPlugin_array = unserialize( file_get_contents('http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip=' . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . '&base_currency=EUR') );

    echo '<h3>A &#8364;800 television from Germany will cost you '.$geoPlugin_array['geoplugin_currencySymbol'] . round( (800 * $geoPlugin_array['geoplugin_currencyConverter']),0) . '</h3>';

} else {

    echo '<h3>A $800 televisor from the US will cost you ' . $geoPlugin_array['geoplugin_currencySymbol'] . round( (800 * $geoPlugin_array['geoplugin_currencyCode']),0) . '</h3>';

}
?>
```

[image: Pais]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]